# How to run exe file in VM using PowerCLI?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

Recently I am working on VMs, using vSphere.
I'm also using PowerCLI to automate some stuff.
I discovered the cmdlet `Invoke-VMScript` which allows scripts to be ran on the VM using PowerShell.

Everything worked just fine until I tried to install a program in the VM:

```
Invoke-VMScript -VM $vm -ScriptText " 'path'.exe" -GuestUser "YourUsername" -GuestPassword "YourPassword"
```

The program won't run, but we can see the process runs. I explored more and discovered it happens in every exe file. It just won't display the GUI, and also won't perform the desired operation.

What can I do to make the PowerCLI run EXE files?

Comment: You *are* running executables. But Windows doesn't allow one session to interact with the desktop of another session for security reasons. If you want to run an installer remotely: investigate whether it provides options for an unattended/silent install.

Comment: hey, thank you for the answer? can't i disable this security configuration? i will try to make the silent install. but i also want to run exe like "notepad", and watch the GUI, not only installations. or, for example, run "tinytask.exe", which performs keyboard and mouse operations you "recorded". is there an option to do that? thank you :)

Comment: You could work around it with [`psexec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx), but my recommendation is: don't.

Comment: understood. i will try to to the silent install and i'll notify you.
but there is something i don't understand. in windows 8 and windows 10 when i try to run "calculator(not calc, calculator), the GUI shows up. i read on internet that calculator isn't normal exe, but something called "metro app". somehow because of that, calculator works.